# Break a string (having alphabetic and alphanumeric values) in 2 parts

Tags: php

I need to slice a string into 2 parts, such that, for example, if the string is `"4s5ee9f8fg"`, I need it as `"4598 seeffg"`

I'm trying with this:

```
$string2 = '132xx';
preg_match("/[0-9]+/",trim($string2),$result);
echo $result[0];
echo $result[1];
```

Here I'm getting just numeric characters, but not alphabetic characters.

Can anyone give a solution?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: check `substr()` php method

Comment: So you're trying to extract the numbers from a string?

Comment: "I'm lazy, do [my task] for me" is not how StackOverflow works - you're expected to at least attempt _something_

Comment: could we see an example of what you have tried ?

Comment: I actually like this question. It's an interesting use case of string manipulation. But as mentioned above, I'll be more inclined to assist if you help me help you. Please edit your question to show what you have tried. And if you have not tried at all yet, please try something and then come back when you have specific questions about the code. :)

Comment: You can access every charachter with $string[index].

Comment: You're close, you are currently only trying to get the numeric characters, which is why that's all you are getting. I figured out a way to do this with `preg_replace` instead of `preg_match`. Try this: `$string2 = '4s5ee9f8fg';
$result1 = preg_replace("/[A-z]+/", "", trim($string2));
$result2 = preg_replace("/[0-9]+/", "", trim($string2));
$finalResult = $result1." ".$result2;
echo $finalResult."\n";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with what you have.

You are currently only trying to get the numeric characters, which is why that's all you are getting. Also, after some testing with different strings, it turned out that your particular regex seems to only works when all the numbers are next to each other. I figured out a way to do this with `preg_replace` instead of `preg_match`.

Try this:

```
$string2 = '4s5ee9f8fg';
$result1 = preg_replace("/[A-z]+/", "", trim($string2));
$result2 = preg_replace("/[0-9]+/", "", trim($string2));
$finalResult = $result1." ".$result2;
echo $finalResult."\n";
```